# Gson -> importing a JSON with objects

Tags: java, json, import, casting, gson

I'm trying to use Gson to import an Json file with an Structure of classes I created. But, although the method toJson works, the structure of objects not.

I have a class called 'Tienda' which have two attributes: (String) Name, (`List<Venta>`) ventas. Where 'Venta' is other class, but when I call the method toJson, the result is a List of objects 'Tienda' where the attribute `List<Venta>` is null. Should I do something different?

This is how I get the file to the `List<Tienda>`:

```
Type listOfMyClassObject = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Tienda>>() {}.getType();
        List<Tienda> tiendas= new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("dd/MM/yyy").create().fromJson(new FileReader("C:\\Archivos\\Ejemplo JSON Ventas.JSON"), listOfMyClassObject);
```

And when I see the content of the result it is like this:

[image: The result is this]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please can you edit your question to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Please avoid using screenshots via links, wherever possible. Provide formatted text for your JSON and additional code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the wrong type field in class. The field must be of type Date (java.util.Date, java.sql.Timestamp, java.sql.Date)

this is a sample task to get a date object

```
//simple Object
Tienda demo = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("dd/MM/yyy").create().fromJson(json, Tienda.class);

//array
List<Tienda> demo = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("dd/MM/yyy").create().fromJson(json, type);
```

this is my example of the class "Tienda"

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Tienda {
  public Date ventas;
}
```

I've written some more tests maybe they'll help you to solve this problem more

```
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class FormatData {

  @Test
  public void testDeserializeArray() {
    //given
    String json = "[{\"ventas\":\"08/04/2020\"}, {\"ventas\":\"08/03/2020\"}]";
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Tienda>>() {
    }.getType();
    //when
    List<Tienda> demo = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("dd/MM/yyy").create().fromJson(json, type);
    //then
    assertEquals(2, demo.size());
    assertEquals(1586296800000L, demo.get(0).ventas.getTime());
    assertEquals(1583622000000L, demo.get(1).ventas.getTime());
  }

  @Test
  public void testSimpleDeserialize() {
    //given
    String json = "{\"ventas\":\"08/04/2020\"}";
    //when
    Tienda demo = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("dd/MM/yyy").create().fromJson(json, Tienda.class);
    //then
    assertEquals(1586296800000L, demo.ventas.getTime());
  }


  @Test
  public void testSerialize() {
    //given
    Tienda demo = new Tienda();
    demo.ventas = new Date(1586296800000L);
    //when
    String json = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("dd/MM/yyy").create().toJson(demo);
    //then
    assertEquals("{\"ventas\":\"08/04/2020\"}", json);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the error was so fool. I have Tienda with capital letter and it should be with lower case. It does't return an error and just let the array as null because it doesn't find the exactly name.